# The method getMax(TreeNode<Pair<K,V>>) in the type Tree<K,V> is not applicable for the arguments (TreeNode<Pair<K,V>>)

Tags: java, generics

TreeMap.java file:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class TreeMap<K, V> {
    private TreeNode<Pair<K, V> > root;

    TreeMap() {
        root = null;
    }

    public void delete(Pair<K, V> data) {
        root = delete(root, data);
    }

    private static <K, V> TreeNode<Pair<K, V> > delete(TreeNode<Pair<K, V> > root, Pair<K, V> data) {
        if (root == null) {                                                 //  empty tree
            return root;
        }
        if (data.compare(root.data) == 0 ) {                                //  target on left side of tree
            root.left = delete(root.left, data);
        } else if (data.compare(root.data) > 0) {                           //  target on right side of tree
            root.right = delete(root.right, data);
        } else if (root.left == null || root.right == null) {               //  root is target, but less than two children
            root = root.left != null ? root.left : root.right;
        } else {                                                            //  root is target, but two children
            root.data = getMax(root.left);
            root.left = delete(root.left, root.data);
        }
        if (root == null) {
            return root;
        }
        root.height = Math.max(height(root.left), height(root.right) ) + 1; //  update height for balanceFactor purpose
        int rootBalanceFactor = getBalanceFactor(root);
        if (rootBalanceFactor > 1) {                                        //  if left subtree is unbalanced
            int leftBalanceFactor = getBalanceFactor(root.left);
            if (leftBalanceFactor < 0) {                                    //  make sure balanceFactor of left node >= 0
                root.left = leftRotate(root.left);
            }
            root = rightRotate(root);
            return root;
        }
        if (rootBalanceFactor < -1) {                                       //  if right subtree is unbalanced
            int rightBalanceFactor = getBalanceFactor(root.right);
            if (rightBalanceFactor > 0) {                                   //  make sure balanceFactor of right node <= 0
                root.right = rightRotate(root.right);                       
            }
            root = leftRotate(root);
            return root;
        }
        return root;
    }

    private Pair<K, V> getMax(TreeNode<Pair<K, V> > root) {
        if (root == null) {
            return null;
        }
        if (root.right == null) {
            return root.data;
        }
        Pair<K, V> result = getMax(root.right);
        return result;
    }

    public boolean search(Pair<K, V> data) {
        boolean result = search(root, data);
        return result;
    }

    private boolean search(TreeNode<Pair<K, V> > root, Pair<K, V> data) {
        if (root == null) {
            return false;
        }
        if (data.compare(root.data) < 0) {
            boolean result = search(root.left, data);
            return result;
        }
        if (data.compare(root.data) > 0) {
            boolean result = search(root.right, data);
            return result;
        }
        return true;
    }

    public void insert(Pair<K, V> data) {
        root = insert(root, data);
    }

    private TreeNode<Pair<K, V> > insert(TreeNode<Pair<K, V> > root, Pair<K, V> data) {
        if (root == null) {                                                 //  create new node at target location
            return new TreeNode<Pair<K, V> >(data);
        }
        if (data.compare(root.data) < 0) {                                  //  target in left subtree
            root.left = insert(root.left, data);
        } else if (data.compare(root.data) > 0) {                           //  target in right subtree
            root.right = insert(root.right, data);     
        } else {                                                            //  target already exists
            return root;
        }
        root.height = Math.max(height(root.left), height(root.right) ) + 1; //  update height for balanceFactor purpose
        int rootBalanceFactor = getBalanceFactor(root);
        if (rootBalanceFactor > 1) {                                        //  if left subtree is unbalanced
            if (data.compare(root.left.data) > 0) {                         //  LR case
                root.left = leftRotate(root.left);
            }
            root = rightRotate(root);                                       //  right rotation necessary in both cases
            return root;
        }
        if (rootBalanceFactor < -1) {                                       //  if right subtree is unbalanced
            if (data.compare(root.right.data) < 0) {                        //  RL case
                root.right = rightRotate(root.right);
            }
            root = leftRotate(root);                                        //  left rotation necessary in both cases
            return root;
        }
        return root;
    }
    
    private int getBalanceFactor(TreeNode<Pair<K, V> > root) {
        if (root == null) {
            return 0;
        }
        int result = height(root.left) - height(root.right);
        return result;
    }

    private int height(TreeNode<Pair<K, V> > root) {
        if (root == null) {
            return -1;
        }
        return root.height;
    }

    private TreeNode<Pair<K, V> > leftRotate(TreeNode<Pair<K, V> > root) {
        if (root == null) {
            return root;
        }
        if (root.right == null) {
            return root;
        }
        TreeNode<Pair<K, V> > rightChild = root.right;
        root.right = rightChild.left;
        rightChild.left = root;
        root.height = Math.max(height(root.left), height(root.right) ) + 1;
        rightChild.height = Math.max(height(rightChild.left), height(rightChild.right) ) + 1;
        return rightChild;
    }

    private TreeNode<Pair<K, V> > rightRotate(TreeNode<Pair<K, V> > root) {
        if (root == null) {
            return root;
        }
        if (root.left == null) {
            return root;
        }
        TreeNode<Pair<K, V> > leftChild = root.left;
        root.left = leftChild.right;
        leftChild.right = root;
        root.height = Math.max(height(root.left), height(root.right) ) + 1;
        leftChild.height = Math.max(height(leftChild.left), height(leftChild.right) ) + 1;
        return leftChild;
    }
}
```

Pair.java file:

```
public class Pair<K, V> {
    K key;
    V value;

    Pair(K key, V value) {
        this.key = key;
        this.value = value;
    }

    public int compare(Pair<K, V> pair1) {
        return this.hashCode() - pair1.hashCode();
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return this.key.hashCode();
    }
}
```

TreeNode.java file:

```
public class TreeNode<T> {
    public T data;
    int height;
    public TreeNode<T> left, right;

    public TreeNode(T data) {
        this.data = data;
        height = 0;
        left = right = null;
    }
}
```

I'm trying to implement a treeMap on my own in Java.

I've written the following code so far.

The methods in TreeMap.java: getMax(), height(), getBalanceFactor(), leftRotate() and rightRotate() are throwing the error: "The method getMax(TreeNode<Pair<K,V>>) in the type Tree<K,V> is not applicable for the arguments (TreeNode<Pair<K,V>>)" same with rest of the above mentioned methods with their respective parameters.

What have I done wrong? How to fix this? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `static` keyword (`static` can't call the instance methods and cannot access the instance fields) and don't hide the generic parameters (the class definition already defines them):

From:

```java
private static <K, V> TreeNode<Pair<K, V> > delete(TreeNode<Pair<K, V> > root, Pair<K, V> data)
```

To:

```java
private TreeNode<Pair<K, V> > delete(TreeNode<Pair<K, V> > root, Pair<K, V> data)
```

Answer (score 1):

You're getting this compilation error because you've messed around with `static` and instance methods.

Your method delete is defined as `static` and you're trying to invoke instance methods from it without the actual class instance:

```
root.data = getMax(root.left); // getMax() - is an instance method
...
root.height = Math.max(height(root.left), height(root.right) ) + 1; // hight() - is an instance method
...
root.left = leftRotate(root.left); // leftRotate() - is an instance method
```

Change the declaration of `delete()` to:

```
private TreeNode<Pair<K, V>> delete(TreeNode<Pair<K, V>> root, Pair<K, V> data)
```

it doesn't need to be static.

Remember, when you're invoking an instance method from another instance method, there's always an implicit reference to `this`:

```
foo(); // means this.foo() if foo() is an instance method
```

But if the enclosing method is `static` there's no implicit reference to `this` because `static` method can be invoked without creating a class instance.